# EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection

Tags: .net, entity-framework, transactionscope, sqlconnection, objectcontext

"EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection"
This is the problem I get when a try to construct an entityconnection providing an open connection.
There is a transactionscope open and I don't want to open a new connection or the transaction would be promoted to a dtc transaction as my understanding is that if I use a single SqlConnection over the multiple entityConnections, I don't need DTC.

So, my code is approximately like this.

Thanks in advance...

```
    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{

    using (SqlConnection dwConn = GetDWConnection(user)) 
    {
        dwConn.Open();
        // I need to do some SQlConnection specific actions first

        //EntityConnection specific actions next
        Func1(dwConn);
        Func2(dwConn); //similar to Func1()
        Func3(dwConn); //Similar to Func1()

    }

}
    Func1(SqlConnection dwConn)
    {
        using (EntityConnection conn = GetSQLEntityConnection(sqlConnection))
        {
            ObjectContext objectContext = (ObjectContext)Activator.CreateInstance(objectContextType, new object[] { conn });
            //few actions
        }
    }
    private EntityConnection GetSQLEntityConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
        {
        //few steps
            EntityConnection entityConnection = new EntityConnection(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());

            EntityConnection sqlEntityConnection = new EntityConnection(entityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(),sqlConnection);
            return sqlEntityConnection;
        }
```

Comment: why don't you pass the same `ObjectContext` instance?

Answer (score 2):

Jakub is completely right. You can create neither `DbContext` nor `EntityConnection` with opened `DbConnection` passed to them.

According to [Diego B Vega’s post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/26/exception-from-dbcontext-api-entityconnection-can-only-be-constructed-with-a-closed-dbconnection.aspx) this issue will not be fixed until EF 6 release ([here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/45) you can vote for it)

The workaround is to open already initialized `EntityConnection` before any operations involving it.

Given `ObjectContext` you can open `EntityConnection` like this:

```
((EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).Open();
```

In case of `DbContext` the `EntityConnection` is available from underlying `ObjectContext`. The code might be like this:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext (DbConnection connection) 
                  : base (connection, contextOwnsConnection: true)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();
    }

    // …
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
        using (var database = new MyDbContext(connection))
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open);
        }
        Assert.IsTrue(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've already found out, you cannot create a new `EntityConnection` from an opened connection.

Instead of passing `SqlConnection` around and creating `EntityConnection` over and over again you should refactor your code and pass `ObjectContext` instead. `ObjectContext` is the root object in EF and you should favour it over `SqlConnection`.